# how to set background image path in scss?

Tags: sass

I am working in react js,I am finding difficulties in setting background image.How to set background image path in scss?

```
.registerpgImage{
       background:url('../../images/registerpgimage.jpeg');
       background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

this is the error I got in console:
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "../../images/registerpgimage.jpeg"

[WDS] Errors while compiling. Reload prevented.

Comment: This code is correct. If you sure that you have a mistake directly in this place, you can try to use double quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are using Webpack and it is failing and therefore not reloading. The way webpack dynamically builds everything, it needs to know where things are located. If your relative file path is correct, try writing your background style as:

`background:url(require('../../images/registerpgimage.jpeg'));`

Answer (score 0):

Change the address of your images. This address is written in the .scss file, but the css file may have a different address to access that photo. Similar to what happened to me.